# playing created Audio-Data has noise and periodical clicking in sound

Tags: c++, linux, qt4, alsa

I write an application, which plays a sound getting from Hardware (like a ring buffer filled with a sinus wave with certain frequency). Everything works fine, and I can playback the created sound correctly except a periodical clicking (maybe at the end of buffer?) and noise.

I initialize and run the Buffer:

```
void Audiooutput::InitializeAudioParameters()
{
    Audio_DataWritten = 0;
    Audio_fragments = 4;
    Audio_channels = 2;
    Audio_BufferSize = 256;
    Audio_Samplerate = 8000;
    Audio_ResamplingFactor = 1;
    Audio_Framesize = 2;
    // (SND_PCM_FORMAT_S16_LE / 8);
    Audio_frames = Audio_BufferSize / Audio_Framesize * Audio_fragments;

    snd_pcm_uframes_t size;
    err = snd_pcm_hw_params_any(pcmPlaybackHandle, hw_params);
    err = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_rate_resample(pcmPlaybackHandle, hw_params, 1);
    //     qDebug()<<a1.sprintf(" % d \t snd_pcm_hw_params_set_rate: %s",Audio_Samplerate,snd_strerror(err));
    err =
        snd_pcm_hw_params_set_format(pcmPlaybackHandle, hw_params,
                     SND_PCM_FORMAT_S16_LE);
    err =
        snd_pcm_hw_params_set_channels(pcmPlaybackHandle, hw_params,
                       Audio_channels);
    err = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_rate_near(pcmPlaybackHandle, hw_params, &Audio_Samplerate, 0);
    //     qDebug()<<a1.sprintf(" % d \t snd_pcm_hw_params_set_rate: %s",Audio_Samplerate,snd_strerror(err));

    if ((err =
         snd_pcm_hw_params_set_periods_near(pcmPlaybackHandle, hw_params,
                        &Audio_fragments, 0)) < 0) {
        qDebug() << a1.sprintf("Error setting # fragments to %d: %s\n",
                       Audio_fragments, snd_strerror(err));
    } else
        qDebug() << a1.sprintf("setting # fragments to %d: %s\n",
                       Audio_fragments, snd_strerror(err));
    err = snd_pcm_hw_params_get_buffer_size(hw_params, &size);
    if ((err =
         snd_pcm_hw_params_set_buffer_size_near(pcmPlaybackHandle,
                            hw_params,
                            &Audio_frames)) < 0) {
        qDebug() << a1.
            sprintf("Error setting buffer_size %d frames: %s",
                Audio_frames, snd_strerror(err));
    } else
        qDebug() << a1.sprintf("setting Buffersize to %d --> %d: %s\n",
                       Audio_BufferSize, Audio_frames,
                       snd_strerror(err));
    Audio_BufferSize = Audio_frames;
    if ((err = snd_pcm_hw_params(pcmPlaybackHandle, hw_params)) < 0) {
        qDebug() << a1.sprintf("Error setting HW params: %s",
                       snd_strerror(err));
    }
    Q_ASSERT(err >= 0);
}

void Audiooutput::ProduceAudioOutput(int n, int mmodes, int totalMModeGates,
         short *sinusValue, short *cosinusValue)
{
    for (int audioSample = 0; audioSample < n;
         audioSample += Audio_ResamplingFactor) {
        currentposition =
            (int)(m_Audio.generalPos % (Audio_BufferSize / 2));
        if (currentposition == 0) {
            QueueAudioBuffer();
            m_Audio.currentPos = 0;
        }
        m_Audio.generalPos++;
        AudioData[currentposition * 2] =
            (short)(sinusValue[audioSample]);
        AudioData[currentposition * 2 + 1] =
            (short)(cosinusValue[audioSample]);
    }
}

void Audiooutput::QueueAudioBuffer()
{
    snd_pcm_prepare(pcmPlaybackHandle);
    Audio_DataWritten +=
        snd_pcm_writei(pcmPlaybackHandle, AudioData, Audio_BufferSize);
}
```

Changing the audiobuffer size or fragments changes also the clicking period.
Can anyone help me with this issue ?
I checked also the first and Last Values. Thy are always difference.

### OS: Ubuntu 11

more detail.

the count of received data is dynamically, and changes depend of different parameters. But I play always a certain part e.g. 128 values or 256 or 512....

//     I get the Audiodata from a hardware (in a Timerloop)

```
    audiobuffersize  = 256;
    short *AudioData = new short[256];
    int generalAudioSample = 0;

    void CollectDataFromHw()
{  
...  
        int n = 0;
        n = GetData(buf1,buf2);//buf1 = new short[MAX_SHRT]
        if(n > 0)
           FillAudioBuffer(n,buf1,buf2)
...
}
    -------------------------------------------
    void FillAudioBuffer(int n, short*buf1, short*buf2)
    {
      for(int audioSample = 0;audioSample < n; audioSample++){
         iCurrentAudioSample = (int)(generalAudioSample % (audiobuffersize/2)); 
         if(iCurrentAudioSample == 0)  {
            snd_pcm_writei(pcmPlaybackHandle,AudioData,audiobuffersize );
             memset(AudioData,0x00,audiobuffersize*sizeof(short));

         }
        generalAudioSample++;
        AudioData[iCurrentAudioSample * 2]   = (short)(buf1[audioSample];
        AudioData[iCurrentAudioSample * 2 +1]   = (short)(buf2[audioSample];

     }
    }
```

---

I changed the audiobuffersize also. If I set it to a bigger size, I have some Echo additional to clicks.

any Idea ?
//----------------------- 
the Problem is

```
snd_pcm_prepare(pcmPlaybackHandle);
```

every call of this function produce a click in  sound !

Comment: Either edit your question, or add an answer yourself, it's impossible to read long chunks of code in comments. By the way, I'm very interested if you get it to work, as I have the same problem my self. :)

Comment: @MartinR: Why you are putting values from buf1[audioSample] and buf2[audioSample] in consecutive positions in AudioData?

Comment: they are real and imag part of audio data. it works also like this in my windows app. it will also get a sound if I write only buf1. but the clicking is the same !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved 
buffer has been played several times before it was filled with the data.

stupid error in the code.missing a parantez  **--> audio_buffersize/2 <-**- 
and therefore the result was very often  if(iCurrentAudioSample == 0) true !!!!!

```
iCurrentAudioSample = (int)(generalAudioSample % (audio_buffersize/2));
if(iCurrentAudioSample == 0)
{
 writetoaudioStream(audiobuffer);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Can't test the source code, but I think that the high-frequency clicks you hear are discontinuities in the sound wave. You have to assure that looping period (or, buffer size) is multiple of wave period.

Check if first and last value of buffer are almost the same (+/- 1, for example). Their distance determines the amplitude of the unwanted click.

Comment: the firs and last value are not the same ! 

They are always difference.

Comment: @MartinR: ok, please try with my suggestion to change the buffer size according to wavelength

Comment: yes I did it also, without any success --> see my new detail in question.